# Where is _.pluck() in lodash version 4?

Tags: javascript, lodash

What happened to `pluck()` in lodash version 4? What is a suitable replacement?

This syntax `_.pluck(users, 'firstName');` is simple to me. Seems that `_.map(users, function(user) { return user.firstName; }` would do the trick but it's not nearly as neat.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Looks like `_.map(users, 'firstName');` should cover it.